# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta? ¿“Imagínate que estás viajando por México” o “Imagínate que estés viajando por México”?

Tags: coloquialismos, subjuntivo

Para ser sincero, ambas formas me parecen correctas, pero me preocupa que la segunda simplemente sea un abuso del  lenguaje, y que la manera correcta de formar el subjuntivo sea la primera.

Cualquier clarificación es muy apreciada.

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la NGLE (25.4o-q) se habla del tema utilizando como ejemplo el verbo *soñar* y luego extendiendo la exposición a *imaginar*, *sospechar* y otros similares. Adjunto debajo capturas de pantalla; resumiendo, detrás de un verbo como *imaginar* puede ir una subordinada en indicativo o en subjuntivo según lo que se quiera expresar. Cuando se trata de una conjetura o hay una negación o ciertos verbos que matizan el significado como *suponer*, se usa el subjuntivo; de lo contrario (en la mayoría de los casos), se trata de una representación mental de un hecho, y se utiliza el indicativo.

La frase del dilema debería ser, por lo tanto, ***“Imagínate que estás viajando por México”*, en indicativo**, ya que el verbo *imaginar* en imperativo es una exhortación a que el oyente se represente o figure voluntariamente un hecho.

Por alguna razón el subjuntivo sí funciona en el pretérito, *“Imagínate que estuvieras viajando por México”*. No sabría explicar por qué.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Fue super útil.